# Different behaviors of <a> tag with download attribute and dataUrl href?

Tags: javascript, html, download

I am experiencing strange behavior in various browsers when trying to use `download` attribute in `<a>` tag when `href` is `dataUrl`.

**Code snippet:**

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = [generated dataUrl];
a.download = filename;
console.log(a.outerHTML);
a.click();
```

**Sample contents of  tag generated** (from console.log line above):

```
<a href="data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,UEsDBAoA...Qwwe=" download="testfile.xlsx" ></a>
<a href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...ElFTkSuQmCC" download="testfile.png"></a>
```

**Console output/behavior:**

- **Chrome**:   Files download as expected, and both png and xls are usable.
- **FireFox**:  Nothing happens. No console warnings/errors shown.
- **EDGE**:

  - *Console message:* Navigation occurred. data:image/png;base64,iVBORw...
  - *Console warning:* DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "".
- **IE11**:     *Console*: nothing; tries to "open data:image/png;base64,iVBORw..." url in current window.

`generated dataUrl`are double-checked and are fine, which is also shown by Chrome behavior.

I thought that `<a href="data:[mime][;base64],[encoded data] ></a>" download="filename.ext"` was pretty much a standard thing by now.

**Question:**

**Is there a better (i.e. cross-browser compatible) way to invoke download of JavaScript generated files?**

Comment: Have a look at [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

Comment: Yes, use FileSaver. Or read notes on download method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: For supported tags use :`https://caniuse.com/#search=download`. It is very useful. Also works for javascript tags `https://caniuse.com/#search=createElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers don't support html5 download attribute.
In that case you can use filesaver.js

```
if(typeof link.download !== 'undefined'){
  //use <a> download
}
else{
  blob = toBlob(imageURIData);
  saveAs(blob, name);//use filesaver.js
}
```